# How to stop arrays from being overwritten in c?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I'm trying to build a prime sieve in C, and in doing so, I ran into a division by 0 error. This was weird to me since I'm dividing by prime numbers (which of course can't be 0).

I managed to trace the problem back to the following piece of code (note the top and bottom debugging prints):

```
int *comb(int primes[], int start, int end) {
    for (int i = 1;i<primes[0];i++) {
        printf("primes[%d] = %d\n", i, primes[i]);
    }

    // Initialize check-list
    int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(int)*(end - start));
    for (int i = start;i < end;i++) {
        numbers[i - start] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 1;i<primes[0];i++) {
        printf("primes[%d] = %d\n", i, primes[i]);
    }
}
```

Of course, the print statements should give the exact same output, but starting at `primes[10]`, they are wholly different. In fact, where this list should contain all the primes from 0 to 100, it now gives the output:

```
primes[1] = 2
primes[2] = 3
primes[3] = 5
primes[4] = 7
primes[5] = 11
primes[6] = 13
primes[7] = 17
primes[8] = 19
primes[9] = 23
primes[10] = 39617
primes[11] = 0
primes[12] = 100
primes[13] = 101
primes[14] = 102
primes[15] = 103
primes[16] = 104
primes[17] = 105
primes[18] = 106
primes[19] = 107
primes[20] = 108
primes[21] = 109
primes[22] = 110
primes[23] = 111
primes[24] = 112
primes[25] = 113
```

It is clear to me that this means my `numbers[]` array is overwriting my `primes[]` array somehow.

What could cause this strange behaviour, and how can I stop it from happening?

**EDIT:** The minimal example I've managed to get this problem down to is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int *Sieve(int n) {
    int found_primes = 0;

    // Initialize prime array
    int *prime = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        prime[i] = i;
    }

    // Start sieving
    for (int i = 2;i < n;i++) {
        // If i isn't sieved out, print it and discard its multiples
        if (prime[i] != 0) {
            found_primes++;
            for (int j = 2 * i;j < n;j += i) { // Discard multiples.
                prime[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("We found %d primes in step 1:\n", found_primes);
    int *prime_list = malloc(found_primes + 1);
    prime_list[0] = found_primes + 1; // Add length information to array.

                                      // Fill prime_list
    int counter = 1; // Skip length element
    for (int i = 2;i < n;i++) {
        if (prime[i] != 0) {
            prime_list[counter++] = prime[i];
        }
    }

    return prime_list;
}

int *comb(int primes[], int start, int end) {
    for (int i = 1;i<primes[0];i++) {
        printf("primes[%d] = %d\n", i, primes[i]);
    }

    // Initialize check-list
    int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(int)*(end - start));
    for (int i = start;i < end;i++) {
        numbers[i - start] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 1;i<primes[0];i++) {
        printf("primes[%d] = %d\n", i, primes[i]);
    }

    // Comb out the non-primes
    for (int i = 1;i < primes[0];i++) {
        // x*primes[i] - start --> needs to be positive
        printf("Start: %d\n primes[%d]: %d\n", start, i, primes[i]);
        double j_start = ceil(start / primes[i]) * primes[i];
        for (int j = j_start; j < end;j += primes[i]) {
            numbers[j - start] = 0;
        }
    }

    // Count primes
    int found_primes = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < end - start;i++) {
        if (numbers[i] != 0) {
            found_primes++;
        }
    }
    printf("We found %d primes in step 2.\n", found_primes);

    // Fill prime_list
    int *prime_list = malloc(found_primes + 1);
    prime_list[0] = found_primes + 1; // Add length information to array.

    int counter = 1; // Skip length information
    for (int i = 0;i < end - start;i++) {
        if (numbers[i] != 0) {
            prime_list[counter++] = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    return prime_list;
}

int main() {
        // Initialize program with user input
        int max_number = 10000;

        // Calculate all needed prime numbers.
        int sqrtn = floor(sqrt(max_number));
        int *prime_list = Sieve(sqrtn+1);

        int *primes = comb(prime_list, sqrtn, max_number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post [mcve] please.

Comment: What are your start and end indexes?  Is it possible they're negative?

Comment: @JohnKugelman The other is just the primes up to 100: `2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97`

Comment: Your problem isn't with `numbers` but with `primes`. We can't see where that came from so that's all I can say.

Comment: It seems like you are printing `numbers`, please post the declaration and initialisation of ̀`primes` and also the value of `start` and `end`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Working on it. Might take a while (I only started with c today, so it's quite a jungle for me still).

Comment: @Missu I've got an example up now. That should help. For easy reference: start=100, end=10000.

Comment: This allocation is wrong: `int *prime_list = malloc(found_primes + 1);` You forgot to multiply by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Incidentally, you can find these kinds of errors with `-fsanitize=address` if you are using GCC or Clang on Linux or macOS. I feel like a static analyzer should be able to find this error too, but I don't have specific advice for how to make that happen.

Comment: Valgrind will also find errors in your code.

Comment: @DietrichEpp This has solved the problem at that section. But in the "comb out the non-primes" for loop, some elements get switched to 0 at i=6 and up. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you correct both bad calls to `malloc`? There are two, they are identical.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I did.

Comment: Please note that in `start / primes[i]` both variables are `int`, so an integer division, returning an `int`, is performed (e.g 3/4 -> 0, 7/5 -> 1).